# Adobe Campaign Classic - Typology rule Questions

Tags: javascript, email, dns, adobe

I am looking to set up the new typology rule to achieve the below conditions in Adobe Campaign.

1. Email domain should be valid.
2. should exclude special characters or non English special characters in email address.
3. Mobile number should be valid for country to country.

Please give some ideas to achieve this in Adobe Campaign?

Comment: Can you describe for the point 1, what you mean with **valid**? The same thing for point number 3,

Answer (score 0):

I tested in Adobe Campaign Classic 9035. You cannot use a Regex in the query editor which is mandated by the use of a topology rule. My suggestion would be to use a Regex to match the email address.

This is more of an example rather than an exact answer because we don't know what you mean by "Valid" you will likely want to create a "non matching" expression, since topology filters remove entries that match the expression. So, tell it what you are expecting, and invert that.

Say you wanted to match all example.com example.net and example.org addresses you could use a regex like `.*@example\.[cno][eor][tmg]` (I know this isn't the best way to do this, purely to show an example). In PostgresSQL this would be like

```sql
select semail from nmsrecipients where semail similar to '.*@example\.[cno][eor][tmg]'
```

For other SQL check how they do Regex. Then look up for email domain and email address validation regular expressions, or make your own. The point you made about "valid" would be [based on the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822) of an email which typically isn't [considered to be parsable with a Regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)

In Adobe Campaign you must do two things.

1. Carefully consider [changing the serverConfig.xml to allow sqlInjection](https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/campaign-classic/using/migrating-to-a-new-version/configuration/general-configurations.html#sqldata). There is NO way to prevent regular operators from also using this feature. So take a great care. Instead, skip this section and make your own function or use mine.
2. Use the SQL Expression in the Filter. Click the drop down next to new and press `SQL`.

[image: Edit Filtering Query Screen in Topology Rules]

Then give it a query which would fit in the "where" part of the query for example

```sql
semail similar to E'%@example.\x5Bcno\x5D\x5Beor\x5D\x5Btmg\x5D'
```

Apparently, Adobe Campaign needs you to escape square brackets. So note that `\x5B` is `[` and `\x5D` is `]`.

[image: The generated SQL]

The more secure way to do this is [to make your own function.](https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/campaign-classic/using/configuring-campaign-classic/api/adding-additional-sql-functions.html)

I ended up making this regular expression function package for Postgres and ACC 9035. Just import into your environment. Edit as necessary.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding='ISO-8859-1' ?>
<!-- ===========================================================================
  Additional SQL functions for Adobe Campaign
  ========================================================================== -->
<package
  author      = "Maeve Kennedy"
  namespace   = "nms"
  name        = "regex-functions"
  label       = "Regex Functions"
  buildVersion= "6.7"
  buildNumber = "9035">

  <entities schema="xtk:funcList">
    <funcList name="regex" namespace="cus">
      <group name="regex" label="Regex">
        <function name="RegexCaseSensitive" type="long" args="(&lt;string&gt;, &lt;pattern&gt;)" 
        help="Returns 1 if matches anywhere in the string else 0. Use ^ and $ characters to enforce matching whole string"
                  minArgs="2" maxArgs="2" display="Regular expression matching">
          <providerPart provider="PostgreSQL" body="cast($1 ~ $2 as integer)"/>
        </function>
        <function name="RegexCaseInsensitive" type="long" args="(&lt;string&gt;, &lt;pattern&gt;)" 
        help="Returns 1 if matches anywhere in the string else 0. Use ^ and $ characters to enforce matching whole string"
                  minArgs="2" maxArgs="2" display="Regular expression matching">
          <providerPart provider="PostgreSQL" body="cast($1 ~* $2 as integer)"/>
        </function>
      </group>
    </funcList>
  </entities>
</package>
```

Adds "Regex" group to the expression editor. Follow the built in documentation. No escaping of [ ] necessary.

*Note/Disclaimer: Check with Munvo whom I work for if you need professional help.*